# String formatting in Python with variable number arguments

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, dictionary, format

I have a `dict` which looks something like

```
A = {
    'test1':{'q0':[0.123,0.234],'phi0':[0.124,0.4325],'m':[9.42,0.3413]},
    'test2':{'q0':[0.343,0.353],'phi0':[0.2341,0.235]},
    'test3':{'q0':[0.343,0.353],'phi0':[0.2341,0.235],'m':[0.325,0.325],'z0':[0.234,0.314]}
    }
```

I want to print each individual dictionary:

```
'test1':                 q0=0.123(0.234) phi0=0.123(0.4325) m=9.42(0.3413)
'test2':                 q0=0.343(0.353) phi0=0.2341(0.235)
'test3': z0=0.234(0.314) q0=0.343(0.353) phi0=0.2341(0.235) m=0.325(0.325)
```

How to do so in Python 3 using the`string.format()`? Since each sub-dictionary has variable number of 'parameters', I am not sure how to accomplish it using some list/dictionary comprehension. Also, if I want to leave some space if that parameter is missing like what is shown, how do I do it? Each dictionary has at most five different parameters (q0,phi0,m,c,z0). I juts print it to the terminal so I don't need something very fancy, but I hope it can be more readible.

Comment: You can consider writing a function which takes a key, value of dictionary as input and returns the output in the required format and the print it.

Comment: Part of what you want is sorting the sub-dictionary keys into the order: ['z0','q0','phi0','m'] either by custom sort order or reverse-alphanumeric. Are you ok with writing that code separately, or do you want to stick it in the formatting code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As both your tests and parameters are in dictionaries, you could first sort them to ensure a consistent ordering. Simple sorting may not work though as if you had `test13`, by default in would appear after `test1`. You could use the Python library [`natsort`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/natsort) to help with this.

As each set of parameters could have missing values, a quick search could be used to create a list of all of the `cols` that are needed. You could then reserve space when printing for rows with missing values:

```
from natsort import natsorted

A = {
    'test1':{'q0':[0.123,0.234],'phi0':[0.124,0.4325],'m':[9.42,0.3413]},
    'test2':{'q0':[0.343,0.353],'phi0':[0.2341,0.235]},
    'test3':{'q0':[0.343,0.353],'phi0':[0.2341,0.235],'m':[0.325,0.325],'z0':[0.234,0.314]},
    'test13':{'q0':[0.343,0.353],'z0':[0.234,0.314]}
    }

sorted_tests = natsorted(A.items())     # Ensure test13 is numerical sorted correctly
# Create a list of all required cols
cols = set()

for test, params in sorted_tests:
    cols.update(params.keys())

cols = sorted(cols)    

for test, params in sorted_tests:
    row = [(col, params.get(col, [])) for col in cols]
    cells = []
    for p, values in row:
        if values:
            cells.append('{:20}'.format('{}={}({})'.format(p, values[0], values[1])))
        else:
            cells.append('{:20}'.format(''))

    print("{:6} : {}".format('{}'.format(test), ''.join(cells)))
```

This would give you the following output:

```
test1  : m=9.42(0.3413)      phi0=0.124(0.4325)  q0=0.123(0.234)                         
test2  :                     phi0=0.2341(0.235)  q0=0.343(0.353)                         
test3  : m=0.325(0.325)      phi0=0.2341(0.235)  q0=0.343(0.353)     z0=0.234(0.314)     
test13 :                                         q0=0.343(0.353)     z0=0.234(0.314)
```

Answer (score 5):

Note that dictionaries are unordered data structures, hence you can't expect any order in printing the items unless you use their ordered equivalent `collections.OrderedDict()`. Nevertheless, you can use a generator expression within `str.join()` method :

```
In [4]: for key, value in A.items():
    print(','.join(("{}: {}={}({})".format(key, t1,t2,t3) for t1, (t2, t3) in value.items())))
   ...:     
test1: q0=0.123(0.234),test1: phi0=0.124(0.4325),test1: m=9.42(0.3413)
test3: q0=0.343(0.353),test3: phi0=0.2341(0.235),test3: m=0.325(0.325),test3: z0=0.234(0.314)
test2: q0=0.343(0.353),test2: phi0=0.2341(0.235)
```

Also note that since we're doing the following inline unpacking it may raise a ValueError if number of the items in lists is more/less than two.

```
for t1, (t2, t3) in value.items()
```

Therefore, make sure that the number of unpacking variables match with the number of items in list.

Comment: Except the OP's output sorts the sub-dictionary keys into (reverse-alphanumeric?) order: ['z0','q0','phi0','m']. And missing tuples appear as blank-padded fields.

Answer (score 1):

Check if `'z0'` is in the keys of the sub-dictionaries, and to those items, apply a slightly different string operation than the ones that don't have that key. Looks a little dirty but produces your output exactly:

```
for k,v in A.items():
    if 'z0' in v:
        print (k,":","{}={}({})".format('z0',v['z0'][0],v['z0'][1]), " ".join("{}={}({})".format(e,t[0],t[1]) for e,t in v.items() if 'z0' not in e))
    else:
        print (k,":                "," ".join("{}={}({})".format(e,t[0],t[1]) for e,t in v.items()))
```

Result:

```
test1 :                 q0=0.123(0.234) phi0=0.124(0.4325) m=9.42(0.3413)
test2 :                 q0=0.343(0.353) phi0=0.2341(0.235)
test3 : z0=0.234(0.314) q0=0.343(0.353) phi0=0.2341(0.235) m=0.325(0.325)
```

Note: If you really need those single quotes around the `test`s, i.e. `'test1'` instead of `test1`, you can add `"'"` to the left and right of `k` in the two `print` statements of mine: `print ("'",k,"'",...`

Answer (score 1):

use a nested loop:

```
for m,x in A.items():
    for y,z in x.items():
        print(m,'{0}='.format(y), z[0],'({0})'.format(z[1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following code based on `for` loop which produces a sorted output:

```
outlist = []
for a in A:
    outstr = a+":"
    for aa in ('z0', 'q0','phi0','m','c'):
        if aa in A[a]:
            outstr += aa+"="+str(A[a][aa][0])+"("+str(A[a][aa][1])+") "
        else:
            outstr += "                "
    outlist.append(outstr)

for i in sorted(outlist):
    print(i)
```

Output:

```
test1:                q0=0.123(0.234) phi0=0.124(0.4325) m=9.42(0.3413)                 
test2:                q0=0.343(0.353) phi0=0.2341(0.235)                                 
test3:z0=0.234(0.314) q0=0.343(0.353) phi0=0.2341(0.235) m=0.325(0.325)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
A = {
    'test1':{'q0':[0.123,0.234],'phi0':[0.124,0.4325],'m':[9.42,0.3413]},
    'test2':{'q0':[0.343,0.353],'phi0':[0.2341,0.235]},
    'test3':{'q0':[0.343,0.353],'phi0':[0.2341,0.235],'m':[0.325,0.325],'z0':[0.234,0.314]}
    }
for i,j in A.items():
    print i+':',
    for x,y in j.items():
        print "{}= {}({})".format(x,y[0],y[1]),
    print 
#output is same as expected
```